# Symbol not found: _PKPaymentNetworkPagoBancomat

Tags: ios, swift, passkit, xcode15

So in my app i have integrated ApplePay with Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d) and my app's minimum iOS version is v16.

What I'm doing is literally mapping web [PaymentNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaypaymentrequest/1916122-supportednetworks) into `PKPaymentNetwork`.
When i run may app on iOS 16.4 simulator it just crashing with following message.

```
dyld[63845]: Symbol not found: _PKPaymentNetworkPagoBancomat
  Referenced from: <BACBF79F-6485-3A1B-84CA-A343341FA5A6> /Users/user.name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2F7896EF-64AE-40CF-B712-DF4F2DCFF887/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D15AF1A-8479-4C03-A674-CF9F3A721573/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Expected in:     <6C22B2D4-5F5B-3FA9-825B-BDA166D45320> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_20E247/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 16.4.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/PassKit.framework/PassKit
```

Here is the code that I'm trying to execute.

> Note that it's working with iOS 17!

```
public enum ApplePayNetwork: String, Codable {
    case amex = "amex"
    case bancomat = "bancomat"
    case bancontact = "bancontact"
    case cartesBancaires = "cartesBancaires"
    case chinaUnionPay = "chinaUnionPay"
    case dankort = "dankort"
    case discover = "discover"
    case eftpos = "eftpos"
    case electron = "electron"
    case elo = "elo"
    case girocard = "girocard"
    case interac = "interac"
    case jcb = "jcb"
    case mada = "mada"
    case maestro = "maestro"
    case masterCard = "masterCard"
    case mir = "mir"
    case privateLabel = "privateLabel"
    case visa = "visa"
    case vPay = "vPay"
    
    public init?(pkPaymentNetwork: PKPaymentNetwork?) {
        guard let pkPaymentNetwork else {
            return nil
        }
        switch pkPaymentNetwork {
        case .amex:
            self = .amex
        case .pagoBancomat:
            self = .bancomat
        case .bancontact:
            self = .bancontact
        case .cartesBancaires:
            self = .cartesBancaires
        case .chinaUnionPay:
            self = .chinaUnionPay
        case .dankort:
            self = .dankort
        case .discover:
            self = .discover
        case .eftpos:
            self = .eftpos
        case .electron:
            self = .electron
        case .elo:
            self = .elo
        case .girocard:
            self = .girocard
        case .interac:
            self = .interac
        case .JCB:
            self = .jcb
        case .mada:
            self = .mada
        case .maestro:
            self = .maestro
        case .masterCard:
            self = .masterCard
        case .mir:
            self = .mir
        case .privateLabel:
            self = .privateLabel
        case .visa:
            self = .visa
        case .vPay:
            self = .vPay
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    public var toAppNetwork: PKPaymentNetwork {
        switch self {
        case .amex:
            return .amex
        case .bancomat:
            return .pagoBancomat
        case .bancontact:
            return .bancontact
        case .cartesBancaires:
            return .cartesBancaires
        case .chinaUnionPay:
            return .chinaUnionPay
        case .dankort:
            return .dankort
        case .discover:
            return .discover
        case .eftpos:
            return .eftpos
        case .electron:
            return .electron
        case .elo:
            return .elo
        case .girocard:
            return .girocard
        case .interac:
            return .interac
        case .jcb:
            return .JCB
        case .mada:
            return .mada
        case .maestro:
            return .maestro
        case .masterCard:
            return .masterCard
        case .mir:
            return .mir
        case .privateLabel:
            return .privateLabel
        case .visa:
            return .visa
        case .vPay:
            return .vPay
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PKPaymentNetwork.pagoBancomat` is only available starting from iOS 17.0. Which means that any mention of this network should be encapsulated inside an availability check such as:

```swift
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    return .pagoBancomat
}
```

But since you're using a `switch`, you're probably going to have to use the `default` clause to deal with this specific network. You'll probably have to do something similar with **tmoney** as this network is also only available starting from iOS 17.0.

However, **it looks like there's something wrong with the `pagoBancomat` network** that goes beyond that. **Even using the `if #available` conditional, my app crashes** at launch on iOS 16.3.

I decided to avoid mentioning `pagoBancomat` altogether for now. But if I'm not alone noticing this issue, I'll file a feedback to Apple, it may be a bug on the SDK level, which could be fixed in a subsequent version of Xcode.

Notes:

- I'm using Xcode 15.0.1.
- I have tried cleaning the project and removing derived data.

Comment: Same, i decided to avoid pagoBancomat!

Comment: OK, I've filed a feedback to Apple: FB13345184. Let's hope this will get fixed someday 